# Как вытянуть данные из атрибута с помощью Xpath запроса через selenium?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

Есть код

```
<div id="post-20629724_1128951" class="_post post page_block deep_active" data-post-id="-20629724_1128951" onclick="wall.postClick('-20629724_1128951', event);" post_view_hash="d6b48097f9db5c778b">
  <div class="_post_content">
```

и `XPATH` запрос к нему `//*[@id="post-20629724_1128951"]`

Вопрос - что нужно добавить к запросу, чтобы селениум вытянул из кода выше значение атрибута(могу ошибаться в терминологии) id, т.е чтобы вывело `post-20629724_1128951`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-20629724_1128951"]').get_attribute("data-post-id")
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всё завелось. До этого битых 3 часа искал инфу о том, как выдернуть значение атрибута, но кроме добавления "собаки" к запросу ничего не находил. Добра тебе :)

Comment: Если мой ответ помог вам, то отметьте его ответом (слева с моим ответом галочка такая, должна загореться зеленым)